# Firefox is too slower than Chrome while query the object path using jsonPath

Tags: javascript

I have one object (array of object) and I am trying to query the path of an object based on id using jsonPath. In Chrome, the query takes 0.01 to 0.02 seconds to execute where as in Firefox it takes 0.1 to 0.2 sec. This is a big performance issue in Firefox for me.

What is the reason for it, is there a solution available to get a greater performance? The next code uses `jsonpath.js`:

```
var students = {
    "Maths": [{
        "Name": "Amit",
        "Marks": 67,
        "age": 23,
        "id": 11
    }, {
        "Name": "Sandeep",
        "Marks": 65,
        "age": 21,
        "id": 22
    }],
    "Science": [{
        "Name": "Shaili",
        "Marks": 56,
        "age": 27,
        "id": 33
    }, {
        "Name": "Santosh",
        "Marks": 78,
        "age": 41,
        "id": 44
    }]
};
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var obj = jsonPath(students, "$..[?(@.id==11)]", {
    resultType: "PATH"
});
console.log(obj);
var endTime = new Date().getTime();
var diffTime = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
console.log(diffTime);
```

Comment: [jsonpath](http://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/)? That's a project which has not been updated since 2007.

Answer (score 1):

try an Negative diggit

```
var diffTime = (endTime-startTime)/999;

    console.log(diffTime);
```